# layer->schedule() does not work

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

```
void HelloWorld::startMovingBackground() {

    CCLog("startMovingBackground...");

    if ( isLeftPressed && isRightPressed ) {
        return;
    }

    CCLog("schedule...");        // OK.......................

    this->schedule(schedule_selector(HelloWorld::moveBackground));
}
```

and

```
void HelloWorld::moveBackground(float f) {

    CCLog("moveBackground %f", f);       // NO....................

    // Do move background...
}
```

But,
moveBackground function is not called. Help me...

==========================================================

Code (Initializing "HelloScene")

```
CCScene* HelloWorld::scene() {
    CCScene * scene = NULL;
    do {
        scene = CCScene::create();
        CC_BREAK_IF(! scene);
        HelloWorld *layer = HelloWorld::create();
        CC_BREAK_IF(! layer);
        scene->addChild(layer);
    } while (0);
    return scene;
}

bool HelloWorld::init()
{
    bool bRet = false;
    do {
        CC_BREAK_IF(! CCLayerColor::initWithColor(ccc4(255, 255, 255, 255)) );

        this->setTouchEnabled(true);

        winSize = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();

        this->setTouchEnabled(true);

        this->createBackgroundParallax();

        this->createArrowButtons();

        bRet = true;
    } while (0);

    return bRet;
}
```

Comment: Its working fine for me.. Try to give time along with the method.. Or simply use scheduleUpdate().. And use your update method to move background... It works perfectly fine :)

Comment: Try to set breakPoint in method startMovingBackground().Maybe you never called 'schedule'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you invoke the `onEnter`, `scheduleUpdate()` may be not working.Try the following:

```
CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getScheduler()->scheduleUpdateForTarget(this,0,false);
```

or

```
CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getScheduler()->scheduleSelector(schedule_selector(NewGame::update),this,0.1,false);
```

Answer (score -2):

you missed an argument in

```
this->schedule( selector, time_interval);
```

If I didn't remember wrong, the default is 0 and it will never get called.